# Gibbs vs. Boltzmann entropies

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I was reading Goldstein's paper [Boltzmann's Approach to Statistical Mechanics](http://math.rutgers.edu/~oldstein/papers/bol.pdf) and he makes the following statement:

> The Second Law is concerned with the thermodynamic entropy, and this
>   is given by Boltzmann’s entropy (1), not by the Gibbs entropy (2).

On the next page he states:

> Certainly contributing to the tendency to identify the thermodynamic
>   entropy with the Gibbs entropy is the fact that for systems in
>   equilibrium the Gibbs entropy agrees with Boltzmann’s entropy.

However [a paper](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/gibbs.vs.boltzmann.pdf) by Jaynes showed that the Gibbs and Boltzmann entropy do not agree for a system in equilibrium and in fact the disagreement is proportional to the inter-particle interactions (in general $S_B \geq S_G$). It is made somewhat confusing by the fact that I'm not sure Jaynes and Goldstein are using exactly the same definition of the Boltzmann entropy. But what Goldstein does make clear is that the Boltzmann entropy is calculated from the 1-particle distribution function, as does Jaynes. This must necessarily exclude inter-particle correlations and so I think is subject to Jaynes' critique.

Does anyone know how Goldstein's statement can be justified?

Comment: They are not using the same notion of Boltzmann entropy. Goldstein (see his equ. (1)) is using the logarithm of the volume of the macrostate: this is *not* based on the 1-particle distribution. Jaynes is using the notion of entropy that Boltzmann used to prove his H-theorem; this one *is* based on the one-particle distribution. Note that the latter definition is of course not the correct one (the one corresponding to the thermodynamical entropy).

Comment: The way Goldstein defines a "macrostate" is based on the 1-particle distribution. He writes:
"[P]artition the 1-particle phase space (the q,p – space) into macroscopically small but microscopically large cells $\Delta_{\alpha}$ and specify (approximately, by providing intervals) the number $n_{\alpha}$ of particles in each cell. Each such specification determines a macrostate, the set of all phase points whose particles are distributed in the manner specified."

Comment: You are misunderstanding him (and Boltzmann). He is partitioning the 1-particle phase space, of course, but then the macrostate is characterized by the number of particles in each cell. The latter depends on all the particles.

Comment: I don't understand you. The 1-particle distribution is calculated from $N$-particle state. This is true but besides the point. Two microstates which differ in interparticle correlations may be characterised by the same macrostate for the simple fact that 1-particle distributions cannot represent correlations. Information on correlations is necessarily "thrown out" when the 1-particle distribution is calculated.

Comment: Think about it this way: what information on a given microstate do you need to determine the macrostate to which it belongs? You do need to know the simultaneous state of all the particles in the configuration.

Comment: I feel like I am repeating myself. Yes, the simultaneous state of all the particles is needed to calculated the 1-particle distribution. This does not change the fact that the macrostates and the Boltzmann entropy depend only on the 1-particle distribution. The Boltzmann entropy is therefore not sensitive to interparticle correlations. This is very straightforward reasoning.

Comment: You're completely wrong. But I feel that you're not really interested in understanding these issues better, so I won't lose any more time trying to explain this to you.